# Git doesn't see new files, only the folder

Tags: git, file, commit

When adding a folder with some new files into my project and doing a git status, git only tells me about the folder and not the files. When I did a add -A only the folder and no files was added and when I push and pull, only the folder and not the files come through.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do your files match a pattern in your .gitignore file?

Comment: Nope, It's prolly just what Daniel said here below.

Answer (score 8):

Let's say you have the following untracked folder:

```
./fruits/
./fruits/apples.txt
./fruits/kiwis.txt
```

If you want to see the files inside the untracked folder:

```
git status -u
```

If you want to stage the untracked folder, together with the files inside it:

```
git add fruits/
```

Answer (score 2):

As git only tracks files and not folders, the behavior regarding push and pull is impossible. It is impossible to add an empty directory to git.
For `git status` however this is expected behavior as all files in the folder are new, because git doesn't track any file inside this folder yet.

Also, check the [git school, challenge 7](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/7). If you type `git status` there, you will see this output, although `octofamily` contains two files:

```
$ git statu­s
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "­git add <file>..." to­ include i­n what wil­l be commi­tted)
#
# blue_octocat.txt
# octofamily/
# red_octocat.txt
```

This is just a simplification in the UI, you still can do `git add octofamily/baby_octocat.txt` (However, not in the git school, because it isn't an actual git client).

A subsequent `git status` would now reflect this:

```
$ git statu­s
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#      new file: octofamily/baby_octocat.txt
#         
# Untracked files:
#   (use "­git add <file>..." to­ include i­n what wil­l be commi­tted)
#
# blue_octocat.txt
# octofamily/momma_octocat.txt
# red_octocat.txt
```

Please note, how it now shows the file(s) inside `octofamily`, because now that folder is known.

Comment: That is very odd because I got an empty folder on my site when I pushed and pulled to it. 

However, how do I start tracking the files in the folder then?

Comment: @JohanDahl: Please see update. The empty folder indeed is strange.

Comment: Ok then there was nothing wrong with my git status I guess. But I did do git add . and also tried git add -A and the files where not added, atleast git status didn't report anything about them.

I finally managed to get them recognized by going inside the folder and doing git add . from there. But shouldn't that work from my root folder where the git project is?

Comment: @JohanDahl: Yes, that should work from the root folder, I just checked it on my local repository. I have to admit, your problems sound a bit odd. Maybe it is a good idea to post that on the git mailing list.

Comment: The behavior described is what I see when I add a submodule, the add for the files in the submodule need to be added within the submodules folder, but only the folder itself is visible from outside the submodule.

Comment: @DavidCulp: Yes that is exactly my issue. Anyway, even though the behaviour is still suspicious, atleast I now know how to bypass it.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify -- you are using submodules?

Comment: @DavidCulp: No, actually I'm pretty new to Git and wasn't aware of what submodules is or how they work until I just googled it. My problem did arise however when I cloned a drupal module into my project. So I did have two git-repositorys, my main repository and then the module that I cloned. I thought they could work independently by themselves but I guess that's what submodules are for.

The problem persisted for me though even when removing the drupal module and downloading it without the git-part.

Answer (score 2):

Note that git will now treat folders containing a hidden `.git` folder as a submodule. You can check them in that way, leaving the folder contents accessible as a separate repository with only a reference stored in the parent repository.

1) You can keep it that way and just use the two repos separately if you prefer, linked by a reference.

2) If retaining the git history of the folders contents is not important, deleting the `.git` folder inside will cause the normal git behavior to return.

3) If you want to retain the history, you can instead use `git subtree` to copy a branch into your new repo. This makes the files editable locally and the history is still accessible.

---

The following command will copy the contents and history of another local repo's current branch into your current local branch.

`git subtree add --prefix=[newFolderName] [/path/to/other/repo] HEAD`

( Replace the square bracketed sections with the name and path of your choice )

Answer (score 0):

Try `git add` one of existing files in the directory. `git status` and it will show all files there as usual. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there was .git directory folder hiding in the subdirectory.  removing it fixed the issue for me.